# Typescript redundant conditions

Tags: typescript

In the following snippet, if I do not check if `config.params` exists inside the map function, typescript will throw me the following error
`Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

But as you can see. on line 2 i'm already checking that `config.params` is not undefined.
I do not understand the need of a second condition to check `config.params`.

```js
  const constructURL = new URL(url, this.url)
    if (config && config.params) { // Checking if config and config params are well defined
      const queryParams = new URLSearchParams()
      Object.keys(config.params).map((x: string) => {
        if (config.params) queryParams.set(x, config.params[x]) // why do I need to check again ?
      })
      constructURL.search = queryParams.toString()
    }
```

Comment: I would say, because it is inside another (arrow) function... And in that scope it was not yet tested...

Comment: Your error is not coming from `config.params` being potentially undefined, but possibly `config.params` is not an indexable with `x`

Comment: It works with the above example @Terry so I dont see how it is checking `x`. It's possible that is caused by the scope

Comment: Even after removing the inner `if` statement I'm not getting an error. Can you reproduce your problem on TypeScript playground? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgJwDYwLwwOQYNwChSSxQAWAlhIiulngdDAQGakDmaMA3rjDzAA4BDBAIC2EAFyduvGQMkBGAEwBmaTwC+uTfnD06UBHGBQAqgCUAMuzABTAO4xzFgBSUANDBLlKASlylGGGcmVhgAMjCGcGYWADpBYTEfThgAelSYAGFiG2AAa1IwNgCosBiYATAAE1LyhNEICoQbGDsbJBQqm2ZbKrVS+gBHOBsEAE8ABSEG63tHSwBlGyFgYinEiGcfPBkAeQAjACtcqFi8mzHNkLj6pNiRAT5nZwAPSWgEQpZk1AA+KRkMmGo0m0zEsQgNigrw813iYIgAG0XgBdPwydTbfr6QzGJwQ5YIVbsYHjdYNWJQEALAxfLZ4dRAA